# What is the point of aria html elements?

Tags: html

I've writing a lot of web pages over the past 2 years now, but there is something I couldn't understand the need of it.
(*aria-labeled, aria-hidden, aria-describely, etc...*)
I know that some of them like aria-hidden could hide the spicfied html element, but what is the main point of aria elements? There is a lot of them and every element has a purpose to use. 
So in conclusion **What's the point of using aria elements with html elements?**

Comment: What did your google search results turn up that you have a specific question about?

Answer (score 2):

HTML aria attributes are a set of attributes that you can add to any HTML element that define ways to make web content and applications accessible to users with disabilities who use assistive technologies (AT).

Please refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA

Answer (score 1):

ARIA is used for people with disabilities who use assistive technologies. For example, if you use role='menu' then the screen reader can interpret it as a menu and read it aloud with enough context for the end-user to understand.